# Why are ciphers using DSS being offered when using DH+AES:!DSS?

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

When I run the following command on Windows 10 with OpenSSL 1.0.2p installed I receive a curious result back (Formatted for readability):

```
openssl ciphers "DH+AES:!DSS:!aDSS:!aNULL"

DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
```

This issue seems to only occur for non-ephemeral implementations of DH (There is no DHE-DSS-... in the list of ciphers). I'd like to use Diffie-Hellman ciphers without using DSS. Is there a way to configure OpenSSL to honor this?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation of ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html):

> aDSS, DSS
> cipher suites using DSS **authentication**, i.e. the certificates carry DSS keys.

To have a closer look at the ciphers you wonder about:

```
$ openssl ciphers -V 'DH+AES:!DSS:!aDSS:!aNULL' | grep DSS
      0x00,0xA5 - DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0x68 - DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)    Mac=SHA256
      0x00,0x36 - DH-DSS-AES256-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS     Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)    Mac=SHA1
      0x00,0xA4 - DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0x3E - DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)    Mac=SHA256
      0x00,0x30 - DH-DSS-AES128-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS     Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)    Mac=SHA1
```

Have a closer look at the 'Au=...' column which describes the **authentication** used. Clearly all of these are using `Au=DH` and not `Au=DSS`, i.e. they are not using DSS for authentication and are thus not covered by the `DSS` string in the ciphers setting. All of these are using `DSS` only within the key exchange as `Kx=DH/DSS` shows.

`Au=DH` essentially means that the certificate contains a static Diffie Hellman key as [subject public key info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7) which is used for authentication and with `Kx=DH/DSS` also as part of the key exchange.